# I don't understand why my form is not validating in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am still new to django. Playing around with a leadmanager app and I don't know why my form is not validating.

views

```
def index(request):
    lead=LeadForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        lead=LeadForm(request.POST)
        if lead.is_valid():
            messages.success(request, f'Thank you for registering. Someone will be contacting you soon.')
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            lead=LeadForm()
            messages.error(request, f'Something went wrong. Please try again later.')
        
    return render(request, "frontend/index.html", {'lead':lead})
```

in index.html

```
<form action="" method="POST" class="lead-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="lead-info">
        <div class="form-control">
            <label for="">Full Name</label>
            {{ lead.fullname }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
            <label for="">Email</label>
            {{ lead.email }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
            <label for="">Phone</label>
            {{ lead.phone }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
            <label for="">City</label>
            {{ lead.city }}
        </div>
    </fieldset>
             <button type="submit" class="btn-pill">Submit</button>
</form>
```

in forms.py

```
class LeadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    class Meta:
        model = Lead 
        fields = ['fullname', 'email', 'phone', 'city', 'contact_preference']
        widgets = {'contact_preference': forms.RadioSelect }
```

Any help is appreciated. contact_preference is rendering FYI, I just cut the code to keep this question not that long.

Comment: remove the `lead=LeadForm()` in the `else` part, and render it with `{{ form }}` in the template. Then it will show the errors. If you render it manually, you need to add for every field the `{{ lead.fieldname.errors }}`: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have this to catch the if/else statement                 {% if messages %}
                    {% for message in messages %}
                        <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
                            <span>{{ message }}</span>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it goes straight to the else statement. I did everything you suggested and it still goes to else statement. I am trying lead.fieldname.errors now.

Comment: @GlennDelostrico in template, where is your 'contact_preference' field?

Comment: @GlennDelostrico: but `fieldname` should be the *name* of the field, so every field. Furthermore in the `else` you should *not* construct a new form, since then the form errors will disappear. The comment is not how to fix the validation, it is about *showing* why validation fails.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem tired adding {{ lead.fieldname.errors }} still goes straight to the else statement

Comment: <fieldset class="lead-preference">
                <legend>Contact Preference</legend>
                {% for choice in lead.contact_preference %}
                    <div class="form-control">
                        {{ choice.tag }}
                        <label for="{{ choice.choice_label }}"> 
                            {{ choice.choice_label }}
                            {{ lead.fieldname.errors }}
                        </label>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </fieldset>

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem contact preference goes after the first fieldset

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so its like late here or early morning however you look at it. I literally copied lead.fieldname.errors instead of lead.phone.erros, lead.email.errors, i forgot i set my phone to phonenumbefields so I have add the country code. Thank you Willem. I'm just tired and retarded lol